# Call global function asynchoronously in C++

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I am getting the following error on compiling the program :

```
q1.cpp: In member function ‘void Course::display(int, int, int (*)(Student))’:
q1.cpp:56:59: error: no matching function for call to ‘async(double (&)(std::vector<Student>::iterator, std::vector<Student>::iterator), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student> >&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
   56 |             auto handle = async(calcClassAverage, mid, end);
```

I am trying to call a global function using async like -

```
class Course
{
public:
    vector<Student> _studentVector;
    
    void display(int x, int y,
                 int (*func)(Student))
    {
        if (!isAverageCalculated)
        {
            auto len = _studentVector.end() - _studentVector.begin();

            _studentVector.begin();
            _studentVector.end();

            auto mid = _studentVector.begin() + len / 2;
            auto handle = async(calcClassAverage, mid, end);
        
    }
```

this is the signature of the global function :

```
double calcClassAverage(vector<Student>::iterator begin,
                        vector<Student>::iterator end)
{<br>
```

I guess I am calling it wrong way. what could be reason for this

Replaced end with the iterator.end(). But now I get the following compilation error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccv9l6B1.o: in function `std::thread::thread<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<double (*)(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > > > >, double>::_Async_state_impl(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<double (*)(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > > > >&&)::{lambda()#1}, , void>(std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<double (*)(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > > > >, double>::_Async_state_impl(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<double (*)(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student> > > > >&&)::{lambda()#1}&&)':
q1.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IZNSt13__future_base17_Async_state_implINS_8_InvokerISt5tupleIJPFdN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIP7StudentSt6vectorIS7_SaIS7_EEEESC_ESC_SC_EEEEdEC4EOSG_EUlvE_JEvEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IZNSt13__future_base17_Async_state_implINS_8_InvokerISt5tupleIJPFdN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIP7StudentSt6vectorIS7_SaIS7_EEEESC_ESC_SC_EEEEdEC4EOSG_EUlvE_JEvEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x33): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What is `end`? (currently, `std::end` overload set, but probably not what you want...)

Comment: `_studentVector.begin();` is noop and could be removed.

Comment: FWIW, `auto len = _studentVector.end() - _studentVector.begin();` can be replaced with `auto len = _studentVector.size()`;

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `async(calcClassAverage, mid, end);` should be `async(calcClassAverage, mid, _studentVector.end());`, or you need to have before it, `auto end = _studentVector.end();`

Comment: did you forget to write `auto end = _studentVector.end();` ? It would help if you explained waht exactly the code is supposed to do or why you think it should work, because its not perfectly clear what your misunderstanding is

Comment: The main issue is with the line `            auto handle = async(calcClassAverage, mid, end);
` which calls the function calcClassAverage asynchornously

Comment: I am trying to call the function calcClassAverge two times asynchronously first half and second half

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I replaces it but then it gives some weird error

Comment: You aren't linking the thread library.  `-pthread` at the command line I think.

Comment: I didnt say that this line would fix your issue, I was just trying to make sense out of your code. Please try to provide a [mcve]